# Http Post from Fiddler giving nullpointreference error and cannot understand why

Tags: http-post, twilio, asp.net-web-api

When I am trying to test my HTTP post via fiddler my MVC4 Webapi gives me Null Pointer reference error right at the first If condition that is checking for the smsReq.Body.
The smsReq is coming as NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my Post Method and the fiddler request. I am using MVC4 Web Api

```
 using System.Web.Http;
 using System.Web;
 using Twilio.TwiML.Mvc;
 using Twilio.Mvc;

 public class ValuesController : ApiController
 {

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Postsms([FromBody]SmsRequest smsReq)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(smsReq.Body.ToString()))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));

        }
        else
        {

            string smsTextType = smsReq.Body.ToString();
            HttpResponseMessage response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, "Hello World");
            return response;
        }
```

This is what my Post looks like from Fiddler:

```
  User-Agent: Fiddler
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Accept: application/xml
  SmsSid: xxxx
  AccountSid: xxxxx
  From: xxxx
  To: xxxx
  Host: localhost:9999
  Content-Length: 5
  Body: abc
```

Comment: Your body is not valid json

Comment: To add to what Darrel said, it looks like you've specified a bunch of headers instead of a json formatted body in your POST.  You'll need to set the Content-Type header to application/json so that WebAPI knows that your sending JSON formatted data to it, then add a JSON object to the request body.

Answer (score 0):

Megan from the Twilio crew here.

As noted above, you must format your JSON like so:

```
[{ 
  message : 'Hello World',
  phonenumber : '+1415XXXXXXX'
}]
```

You can find this example in [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/04/build-an-sms-queueing-system-using-azure-and-100-lines-of-code.html) using the [.NET Helper Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install).