# how to read Twilio POST parameters in C# using TwiML?

Tags: http-post, twilio, asp.net-web-api

How to read the Twilio POST parameters for incoming calls? I am trying to use the TwilioController but I am not able to get the Body and the SmsSid using the SmsRequest. Can somebody help me with an example in C# as I am using WebApi. 
I tried passing the POST parameter using Fiddler but the value is coming as Null. So I am not sure if I am reading correctly.

I even tried doing this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody] string smsReq)
    {
        return smsReq;
       // return smsReq.Body + " " + smsReq.SmsSid;
    }
```

But I am getting null for smsReq when I pass the value from Fiddler.

This is what I passed from Fiddler:
     User-Agent: Fiddler
     Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     Accept: application/xml
     Host: localhost:56846
     Content-Length: 13

```
 { '': "Test"}
```

Tried the above using just {="Test"} but no value. smsReq is coming as NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You should be able to use the SmsRequest object a the parameter in the Post method:

```
public void Post([FromBody]SmsRequest) {}
```

I used Fiddler to test this, passing this snippet of Json as [the Body of the POST request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request):

```
{
 "Body":"asdasdasdas",
 "From":"sadasdasds"
}
```

You also have to make sure to set the Content-Type header of the request to "application/json" to WebAPI knows that your passing it JSON so it can deserialize it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But I thought Web Api does not allow you to specify multiple strings as parameter in Post. 
See here: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Please correct me if I am wrong. I did use the SmsRequest object initially as the parameter as that way I get all the parameters. But I am not able to understand how to read them or pass them to my Post in Fiddler. For reading them do I need to create a separate class to do get-set to read those from SmsRequest? Can you please help as I am stuck right there. Thank you.

Comment: See my above edits. I tried a simple test to see how it is working but I got NULL.

Comment: I edited my original answer because you are right, Post appears to accept only one parameter.  I think the issues you are running into still have to do with how you are testing the endpoint.  Based on your other post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005546/http-post-from-fiddler-giving-nullpointreference-error-and-cannot-understand-why) you are not passing a valid Body for Web API to parse.  I set up a test using the method signature above and used Fiddler to test it and it worked as I expected.

Comment: If it is not too much can you please post the code as to how you are reading and returning the SmsRequest.Body or SmsRequest.SmsSid? I am trying to read it but I am not sure if that is where the problem is. If you see my other post I am trying to read the smsReq.Body but it is throwing null point exception. Would appreciate your help here. Thank you.

Comment: Do we need to manually code to deserialize the request or would the web api know that it needs to do? A newbie to web api.

Comment: Twilio sends the request parameters formatted as a Json object and a Content-Type header of application/json.  This means WebAPI should be able to automatically deserialize the json object using Model Binding.  Why don't we take this to email: devin [at] twilio [dot] com.